# Validated an input that's outside of the ReactiveForms model

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-zm7v7j?file=app/app.component.html)

I am using an Angular Reactive form that has 3 inputs, each having its own validation. I have an input that is not part of the form - its an input that sits inside its own component where it has its own reactive form.

I am trying to pass on a property of `[disabled]="registerForm.invalid"` that comes from the make up of the 3 inputs on that view. e.g. if they are all valid "then send value false", if one is invalid "then send value true". This will make the single input either disabled/enabled. `[disabled]="true or false"` works so I know that the issue is with reading the validity of the form.

I thought `registerForm.invalid` would send an updated value of true/false on every input change in the reactive form therefore sending the value on that I require.

*An option* could be to have a `ngOnChanges` that listens for input changes whether they are valid of not and assign a true/false bool to `this.disabled` and pass that through to the component. - however, I am sure there is a simpler way here.

**HTML**

```
<app-input label="Search" [value]="" [disabled]="registerForm.invalid ? true : false"></app-input>
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-zm7v7j?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: In my opinion using ngOnChanges is simple way.

Comment: The updated `disabled` value gets passed to your `InputComponent` but the point is that the form control is not registered in any Angular form. So Angular is not synchronizing the `disabled` property on the control with the `disabled` property on HTML `input` element.

Comment: Sorry @Tom, I missed the mention of the `ngOnChanges`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the form control in the `AppInputComponent` is created on `ngOnInit`. When `<app-input` would receive a new value, `ngOnInit` would not be triggered.

You might leverage getter and setter to solve it ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-2hrbth?file=app/input.component.ts)):

```js
  @Input('disabled') get disabled() {
    return this.control.disabled;
  } 
  set disabled(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.control?.disable();
    } else {
      this.control?.enable();
    }
  }
```

`this.control` will be null when the initial value would be set for the property. It happens before `ngOnInit`.

Or `ngOnChanges` as you mentioned

```js
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.disabled) {
      if (changes.disabled.currentValue) {
        this.control.disable();
      } else {
        this.control.enable();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Getter and setter approach looks interesting. Not sure how I can get that to work on the example you provided

Comment: sorry, I missed a few tiny things. Stackblitz updated

Comment: Thanks a lot - I have never seen this approach before. Prefer this to ngOnChanges

Comment: There is another similar question based off the back of the above. Moving out one of these inputs into its own component but remaining the validation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68473527/send-validation-from-a-componentised-reactivefrom-input-to-another-reactiveform