# Send validation from a componentised ReactiveFrom input to another ReactiveForm

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

A traditional ReactiveForm you specify all inputs and add formControls and validation to those inputs on the related component HTML file. I am moving some of these inputs into their own components so they become sharable and reusable.

In my example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-qgmtaj?file=app/app.component.html) there is already logic to use the validation to disable/enable the search input based on the form validation. However, now that I have moved one of these inputs into its own component, that relationship of being in the same `formBuilder` form for validation purposes no longer applies.

**component.ts**

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
     // password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
    });
```

I've commented out the password input as I am no longer building it in this form, however I still want to know its validation and apply that to this form so that search will only enable once all 3 inputs have been filled in and pass validation rules. Currently you only have to complete first and last name to enable the search input field.

Password now looks like this :
**HTML**

```
<password-input label="Password" [value]=""></password-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can inject ControlContainer inside password-input component to get access to parentFormgroup. Then we can add password form control to existing formGroup dynamically.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'password-input',
  templateUrl: './passwordinput.component.html'
})
export class PasswordInputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('value') value = '';
  @Input('label') label = 'test label';
  control: FormControl;
  formGroup:FormGroup;
  constructor(private controlContainer:ControlContainer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const parentForm = (this.controlContainer['form'] as FormGroup);
    parentForm.addControl('password',new FormControl(this.value,[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]));
    this.control = parentForm.get('password') as FormControl;
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" [formControl]="control" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-z4vj6g?file=app/passwordinput.component.html)